# Getting Started with PHP Extension-Development

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

Please suggest help articles or tutorials about PHP "low" level С-modules programming interface.

Answer (score 22):

Searching through my bookmarks, only links I found are those :

- [Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend)
- [Extension Writing Part II: Parameters, Arrays, and ZVALs](https://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals)
- [Extension Writing Part II: Parameters, Arrays, and ZVALs [continued]](https://devzone.zend.com/318/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals-continued)
- [Extension Writing Part III: Resources](https://devzone.zend.com/446/extension-writing-part-iii-resources)
- [Wrapping C++ Classes in a PHP Extension](https://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension)

If you are really interested by the subject, and ready to spend some money on it, you could buy the book [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) *([some pages are available as preview on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=zMbGvK17_tYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Extending+and+Embedding+PHP&ei=KqeOSoeML4bMM4aL3LAH#v=onepage&q=&f=false) too)* ; I've seen a couple of times that it was **the** book to read when interested on this subject *(In fact, I've just bought it ^^ didn't have the time to read it yet, though :-( ; the first pages seem OK...)*

BTW, the author of that book is also the author of the first four articles I linked to ;-)

Comment: +1 Interesting. Do you know by chance on which Forums the C devs discuss about PHP extensions?

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: Also, the book in question has been published in 2006, and judging by the description it has not been updated (Sams Publishing; 1 edition (June 9, 2006)) which practically makes it obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

Read this: https://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend. It's probably the only useful tutorial I've ever met.

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

I put my favourite links into a [short blog post](http://simonholywell.com/post/2010/09/15-excellent-resources-for-php-extension-development.html) whilst writing [php_ssdeep](http://pecl.php.net/ssdeep), which maybe helpful for people looking for extension development information.

http://simonholywell.com/post/2010/09/15-excellent-resources-for-php-extension-development.html