# Searching for tutorials on writing PHP modules?

Tags: php, module

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Started with PHP Extension-Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311389/getting-started-with-php-extension-development)

Has anyone got some resources on how to write PHP (> 5.2.x) modules in C/C++? Besides that would it be advisable to code such modules for efficiency gains on maybe sorting large heaps of search results and the like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311389/getting-started-with-php-extension-development

Comment: Thanks VolkerK. Didn't find it cause it's tagged as "extension writing". Thumbs up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a series of tutorial on Zend's site about [Extension Writing](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021). Also there is a good paper about [Extending PHP](http://www.loadpdf.com/Extending_PHP.pdf) written by Wez Furlong.

Comment: Both links are not working.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual has a whole chapter about this topic:

[PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide to the Zend Engine](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)

Comment: Strange I never tripped over that. Been there a quadrillion times probably. Thanks anyways.