# Best approach to use a CPP SDK package in PHP

Tags: php, sdk, integration, php-extension

I have to integrate into my system a third party system, which gives me a SDK, written in CPP.
Our application uses PHP as the main language.
What would be the best and/or shortest development to expose the needed functionality in the SDK to my PHP application?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311389/getting-started-with-php-extension-development) may be helpful

Comment: @Michael Mior - thanks, I actually have some knowledge in that area, I wish to avoid developing an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), which was developed by Facebook. Not sure your exact use case, but you can easily setup a server in once language then use their code generation engine. It works with C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml.

Comment: These two posts cover [building a C++ server](http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/apache-thrift-tutorial-the-sequel/) and [a PHP client](http://chanian.com/2010/05/13/thrift-tutorial-a-php-client/).