# How to use C static library (.a file) in PHP

Tags: php, c++, static, .a

In one of our project we are **specifically and compulsorily** required to create **C++ static libraries (.a files)** , and then use them **in PHP (web Application).** We are successfully able to create .a files, now wondering if anyone can help us in identifying how to use them in PHP.
The " .a file " will accept some input data, and will return some output that can be used in the web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial on how to create PHP extensions. I used that in the past and it works well.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150408110240/https://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311389/getting-started-with-php-extension-development. there is a nice tutorial linked for complete manual development of a php extension

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have gone through the link earlier also, and once again. But I am looking for a solution which is independent of any framework libraries like zend, also the solution which can work on Windows platform.

Comment: you cant load native code with php, so you need to create a php extension. -- also, if there is something supporting loading native code from php, it needs to be a c dynamic library (*.dll on windows and *.so on linux). so your options are: create an php extension (easiest way) or search for a dynamic library loader and create a platform specific dynamic library

Comment: Hi Criss, thanks, I will definately like to go for creating php extension, but for me it seems to be little difficult, as my C++ prog may have some higher degree of mathematics and statics involved refering to several external libraries written in C++, I have gone thru the links like http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/ , but didn't find any easy way to create the entension when my c++ code may contain several source and header files. Any suggestions please..

Comment: Hi, initially I find the tutorial and the process of creating the php extension a little cumbersome, but once you are on with proper setups and configuration the entire process is easy and worth. Just to highlight one need not to convert the entire C++ code and all libraries to php extension, they can just expose few core methods which can be provided in the extension.